# Retrieve List of strings in VBScript from .Net COM class

Tags: c#, vbscript, com-interop

My current employer has some old/legacy VBScript routines that call some old/legacy .Net programs  and I am trying to get up to speed on how they work. Good tutorials are hard to find so I created a simple .Net program with a couple of functions and some VBS code to call them. For the primitive return types everything works as expected but I am having issues with complex objects.

The C# interface:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("67F6AA4C-A9A5-4682-98F9-15BDF2246A74")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IClass1
    {
        string Hello();
        List<string> HelloList();
    }
}
```

The C# concrete class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("D24536F5-ECD9-482B-8C57-C9EC2195546D")]
    public class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "Hello world, how are you?";
        }
        public List<string> HelloList()
        {
            List<string> rtn_list = new List<string>();
            rtn_list.Add("String1");
            rtn_list.Add("String2");
            rtn_list.Add("String3");
            rtn_list.Add("String4");
            return rtn_list;
        }
    }
}
```

And my VB Script:

```
' --------------------------------------------------------------
' Testing for calling .Net Framework from vbs
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Call CheckArguments
Call GetHelloTest1
Call GetHelloTest2

' --------------------------------------------------------------
' Sub  : GetHelloTest2
' Desc : Create the COM object and call a function that 
'        returns an array of strings
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Sub GetHelloTest2
    Dim objObject
    Set objObject = WScript.CreateObject("ClassLibrary1.Class1")
    Dim objOutput
    Set objOutput = objObject.HelloList

    ' ?? Not sure how to iterate over the list ?? 
    'WScript.Echo objObject.Hello

End Sub


' --------------------------------------------------------------
' Sub  : GetHelloTest1
' Desc : Create the COM object and call a simple function
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Sub GetHelloTest1
    Dim objObject
    Set objObject = WScript.CreateObject("ClassLibrary1.Class1")
    Dim objOutput
    objOutput = objObject.Hello
    WScript.Echo objOutput
End Sub


' --------------------------------------------------------------
' Sub  : CheckArguments
' Desc : Verify the arguments and create a dictionary object
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Sub CheckArguments
    text = "Arguments" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments       ' Create object.
    For i = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1        ' Loop through all arguments.
        text = text & objArgs(i) & vbCrLf ' Get argument.
    Next 
    WScript.Echo text ' Show arguments using Echo.
End Sub
```

Everything works great except the call to HelloList, which looks like its returning something but I can't figure out how to iterate over the list in the VBS code? No error is returned and I can use VS2017 to debug and step through the code, the quick watch shows this {...} so I think it returned something but I'm not sure what that something is?

Comment: One easy way is to replace `List<string>` by an (old) `ArrayList`. ArrayList is ComVisible.

Comment: You in general want to avoid using any type that is not [ComVisible(true)], none of the generic types are since neither COM nor any non-.NET language knows anything about generics.  Aim low, System.Collections.IEnumerable lets you use For Each in vbscript and is efficient.  An array can work, but is not efficient.

Comment: Simon, your answer worked, thanks.

Comment: jdweng, not sure where to go with this? If VBScript supports reflection you would need to provide an example so I can see how it works, thanks for responding though.

Comment: Hans; IEnumerable did not work for me, if you can provide some code to show this in action that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I am by no means an expert but this worked for me in one of my projects

```
// .COM
[ComVisible(true)]
public object GetSomeStringsForCom()
{
    return GetSomeStrings.Cast<object>().ToArray();
}

// .Net
ComVisible(false)]
public IEnumerable<string> GetSomeStrings()
{
    IList<string> retval = new List<string>();
    retval.Add("hello 1");
    retval.Add("hello 2");
    retval.Add("hello 3");
    return retval.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'll probably get fried for this answer, but that will help to better my own ignorance :)

Comment: Generic classes are not usable over COM. Providing a function to convert an IEnumerable to an ArrayList works.